# How can I organize web buttons?

Tags: html, css

I want to make a web page with 5 buttons styled in this way:

[image]

Here is my HTML code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en"></html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>ROT Control Panel</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="controlPanel.css"/>
</head>

<button class="button button1">Forward</button>
<button class="button button2">Left</button>
<button class="button button3">Stop</button>
<button class="button button4">Right</button>
<button class="button button5">Backwards</button>
```

What should my CSS code be ?

Comment: Even if you absolutely want to use Css, have you tried anything yet or you are just asking for someone to solve it for you?

Comment: _“What should my CSS code be ?”_ - please go read [ask].

Comment: @Seblor — CSS is the correct tool to do presentation with. HTML tables should not be abused for layout. Why are people still making this mistake after 24 years?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the buttons with container divs and leverage [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to justify the contents in the center. It's important to give the buttons the same size, so that they align properly, and scale the containing divs accordingly so that the buttons don't overflow or wrap.

Here is a runnable snippet.

```css
.container {
    width: 300px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.button {
    width: 100px;
}

.button3 {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <button class="button button1">Forward</button>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <button class="button button2">Left</button>
    <button class="button button3">Stop</button>
    <button class="button button4">Right</button>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <button class="button button5">Backwards</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use grid on a parent container and setup the template for and the child buttons to fill them. I would pick grid over flexbox here because:

1. It would be much simpler to organise html-wise (much more pleasing for developers and shows experience).
2. Grid is meant for 2 dimensional layouts.

This should work for you:

```
<div class="container">
  <button class="button">Forward</button>
  <button class="button">Left</button>
  <button class="button">Middle</button>
  <button class="button">Right</button>
  <button class="button">Backwards</button>
</div>
   
<style>
  .container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 33.33% 33.33% 33.33%;
    grid-template-rows: 33.33% 33.33% 33.33%;
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #87CEEB;
  }

  .button {
    margin: 20px;
  }

  .button:nth-child(1) {
    grid-column-start: 2;
    grid-column-end: 3;
  }

  .button:nth-child(2) {
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 2;
    grid-row-start: 2;
    grid-row-end: 3;
  }

  .button:nth-child(3) {
    grid-column-start: 2;
    grid-column-end: 3;
    grid-row-start: 2;
    grid-row-end: 3;
    background: red;
  }

  .button:nth-child(4) {
     grid-column-start: 3;
     grid-column-end: 4;
     grid-row-start: 2;
     grid-row-end: 3;
  }

  .button:nth-child(5) {
    grid-column-start: 2;
    grid-column-end: 3;
    grid-row-start: 3;
    grid-row-end: 4;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the work is done by changing up your markup. In my example I split the buttons up into 3 divs, one for each row, and then aligned them all at the center of the container, and made sure the buttons were the same width.

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
       <button class="button">Forward</button>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <button class="button">Left</button>
      <button class="button red">Stop</button>
      <button class="button">Right</button>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <button class="button">Backwards</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  width: 20rem;
}
.row {
  text-align: center;
  padding: .2rem;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.button {
  width: 5rem;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use the div and the span tag and specify the position you want your buttons have using the align-center in case.

Comment: How? (And web standards don't have anything called "align-center" in them).